# How to get the attribute value of the last element?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

**Input XML**

```
<pageMeta>
  <trail target="/">SAIR Home</trail>
  <trail target="/handle/10862/1">SEAFDEC Aquaculture Department</trail>
  <trail target="/handle/10862/46">SEAFDEC/AQD Publications</trail>
  <trail target="/handle/10862/85">Institutional and Meeting Reports</trail>
  <trail target="/handle/10862/699">Institutional Reports</trail>
  <trail target="/handle/10862/527">Annual Reports</trail>
</pageMeta>
```

Using `select="pageMeta/trail[@target][last()]`, I get the **Annual Reports** value. How can I get the value of the last `@target`attribute which is `/handle/10862/527`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply put the attribute name as the last step of the XPath expression to return the attribute :

```
select="pageMeta/trail[@target][last()]/@target"
```